# split total across Excel date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

What am I doing wrong. How can divide the total amount between the start and end months? The objective is to fill in the correct month based on the start and end date. This is the formula I used  " =IFERROR(IF(OR(F$4<($B8-1),(F$4+1)>$C8),0, $A8/ROUND($D8,0)),"")" without the quotes. It goes haywire if the date is greater than 2. Thank you for assisting.

Comment: will keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are given the total and want to equally split that total across given months? Based on the image provided the only error is on "Person 1" then?

If I am interpreting correctly, this works:

```
=IF(AND(F$2>=EOMONTH($B3,-1)+1, F$2<$C3),
ROUND($A3/$D3,0),"")
```

Disregarding the cells, it is something like:
`=IF(AND(Month>=Start, Month<End), ROUND(Total/Total_Months, 0), "")`

[image]

Comment: person 1 didn't split across the two months. If this is fix then i know we can have it working when the dates are adjusted.

Comment: EOMONTH is a new formula for me. It's working

Comment: If i changed the end date to 9/2/21. How can i get the total months to count as 2 instead of 1? at the moment i subtracted the date and divide by 30.4, but after using your formula I realized it would be nice if i can get the total month in the range. I tried datedif() but it doesnt work if the range is in the same month.

Comment: If the month's are in the same year, you can do ```=MONTH(End)-MONTH(start)+1```. But if the months go over to different years, you could just convert them to a number first. Something like ```=NUMBERVALUE(YEAR(end)&IF(MONTH(end)<10, "0"&MONTH(end), MONTH(end)))-NUMBERVALUE(YEAR(start)&IF(MONTH(start)<10, "0"&MONTH(start), MONTH(start)))+1```